# Sending data to script from hyperlink

Tags: html, post

is there any way I can do something like in my example below but with normal hyperlinks ? I can't use drop down menu.

//edit: I have a web page and a script, on web page now i have drop down menu where user choose some values and submit them, script then do the work.
I just need to sent 3 values to script. (user must choose this values)
Hope its clearly now

this is part of code on my page:

```
 <form action='script/script.py' method='post'>
                <select name = 'menu0'>
                    <option value='x'>X</option>
                    <option value='y'>Y</option>
```

//
And also is there any easy way to remember what user set in dropdown menu ?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean exactly? How about you put in some code for what you want to do (even if you are not sure whether it is valid)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use `POST` method in hyperlink, if your server code support `GET` method then you can create separate links for multiple options

```
<a href="script/script.py?menu0=x">x data</a>
<a href="script/script.py?menu0=y">y data</a>
....
.....
```

Other solution: This should also helpful you, as above create multiple links, you can hidden your form and submit `form` from `<a>` tag `onclick` event

Answer (score 0):

With Hyperlink you can use GET method which is more easy to embed in the link like this :

```
<a href="script/script.py?menu0=x"> X </a>
<a href="script/script.py?menu0=y"> Y </a>
```

So make this work, you will be needing to change your script.py code, that make use of GET function instead of POST.

And easy way to remember what user set in dropdown menu is to store the input you GET via your script to a session variable when script.py gets executed. You can then use that session variable in whole scope of your application i.e. any other python scripts. Refer Session variables for this.